# PHP Ticks and Declare construct

Tags: php, declare

```
function myfunc()
{
    print "I will pass!";
}
register_tick_function("myfunc");
declare(ticks=1)
{
}
```

I wrote the following code in order to understand the subject of "ticks" used with the "declare" statement in php and have no idea why the out put is:
    "I will pass!I will pass!I will pass!"
I have seen the manual section of the declare construct but I find it incomplete in its explanation 
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php

Comment: I am learning the subject of "ticks" using the "declare" structure but do not have a full understanding of it to use it. I have no idea why the output is: "I will pass!I will pass!I will pass!"

Comment: According to http://phpadvocate.com/blog/2010/01/using-declare-and-ticks-with-php/#content, it is a bug with the declare construct.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this [link](http://forum.junowebdesign.com/php-articles/22319-ticks-php-construct-youve-never-used.html) helps for better understanding about ticks.

After executing the above statements the result I got was "I will pass!I will pass!".
Tick was executed after every statement.

Comment: Seems like the parser adds to the execution of the ticks function because of a low level statement that is not visible to the user, i. e. under the hood type of stuff.